# Как выбрать 2 селектор?

Tags: jquery

В общем, есть типа, что-то такого

```
<div class="login">
    <div id="alert"></div>
</div> 
<div class="login2" style="display:none;">
    <div id="alert"></div>
</div>
```

Как выбрать 2 селектор #alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.login2 #alert')
```

Comment: спасибо, что-то я дико затупил

Comment: Два одинаковых идишника. - это как минимум неправильно и как максимум ошибка джаваскрипта.

Comment: @ROOT, никакой "ошибки джаваскрипта" не будет( и вообще не понятно, о какой ошибке идет речь )! Так называемый "джаваскрипт" вернет самый первый элемент с данным ID, найденный в DOM-модели HTML-документа, т.е элемент с индексом [0].

Comment: Согласен, но это применить только к jQuery, чистый джаваскрипт выдаст ошибку

Comment: @ROOT, да ладно !? А не могли бы вы процитировать данную ошибку?

Класс, с каких это пор JS ошибки стал выдавать =) @ROOT, это полная чушь.

Comment: @ROOT, ну куда же вы пропали? Жду "ошибку" =)

Comment: Согласен, не прав ошибки не будет ! Но не правильно использовать 2 одинаковых ид на одной странице

Comment: @ROOT, что ж вы сами себе противоречите...

Comment: противоречие то в чем?

Answer (score 6):

ID на то и ID, что он уникальный идентификатор.

Не правильно использовать два или более тега с одинаковыми идентификаторами.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю! Но кто знает, что там за ситуация такая...

Comment: jQuery поведет себя не так как нужно с несколькими одинаковыми айди. Нужно сменить на классы!

Comment: Два одинаковых ID`шника могут быть просто привязаны к одному CSS стилю, так что, скорее всего, здесь идут два одинаковых именно из-зи каскадных стилей.

Comment: Если из-за стилей, то тем более, на классы заменить.

Comment: [Чем отличаются `id` и `class`][1]

  [1]: http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2006/01/22/id-class-difference/